# how to connect linkedin from node js. Or how to get access token from node js

Tags: node.js, express

Here is my code. Now IN.API.Profile("me") function not working. They return 404 error with message like "v1 was deprecated". So anyone can help me. 
Thanks in advance.!!

```
IN.User.authorize(() => {
    if (IN.User.isAuthorized()) {

        IN.API.Profile("me").fields([
            "id", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "positions", "location",
            "num-connections", "emailAddress", "publicProfileUrl", "picture-urls::(original)",
            "publications", "languages", "skills", "certifications", "educations", "volunteer",
            "recommendations-received","date-of-birth",
        ]).result((data) => {
            console.warn(data);
        }); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What is incomprehensible is in the message: `v1 was deprecated`?

In end support for this api version. Update the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-linkedin-v2

//edit, sample code

```
let in = new LinkedInRestClient(...)
let access_token = await in.getAccessToken(...)
in.getCurrentMemberProfile(fields, access_token).then()
```

Or for user profile: use [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context) and method `getAuthorizationUrl` to generate url, and then implement `redirect_url` route to store user `access_token`

Comment: I'm not saying like that.  i need to resolve now. now i'm getting "{\"error\":\"invalid_request\",\"error_description\":\"Unable to retrieve access token: authorization code not found\"}"

For authorization api url : https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=<<client_id>>&redirect_uri=<<redirect_url>>&state=state&scope=r_basicprofile%2Cr_basicprofile_2

It returns null response.

Comment: Probably you must reauthorize your app. Error says: `authorization code not found`, so find how to pass it to library

Comment: Yeah thanks. But if you have sample code for node js/javascript, then help me

Comment: It's simple, everything is in the library code. See method and follow to official doc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed 3-legged OAuth method. In Doc mentioned initially call authorization api. In Success case, they return response with redirect url. But some times i'm not received proper response. So is there any other api url, to get api response.

Comment: Did you make check for [this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context#application-is-rejected)? It's not a library problem, because [it uses `request`](https://github.com/agrigory1982/node-linkedin/blob/master/lib/LinkedInAPI.js#L182-L185)

Comment: Yes of course. It's my mistake. Now working fine. Can you tell me what parameter should i send this. 
new LinkedInRestClient(...);

Comment: argh... https://github.com/agrigory1982/node-linkedin/blob/master/lib/LinkedInAPI.js#L22